# Attribute already defined when using AIDE

Tags: java, android, attributes, attr, aide-ide

I have an application that runs fine in eclipse but i was trying to import it into AIDE for android so that I can code on the go but importing is giving me errors. Ive noticed in AIDE its a bit more tricky to get things running properly. I had already added google-play-services project as a libray but I still had errors up until the point I actually went into the libs folder and added the actual jar as well.

Now I have cleared all errors except for about 100 "Attribute already defined" inside:
`gridlayout_v7/res/values/attrs.xml`

`actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs_attrs.xml`

`google-play-services_lib/res/values/maps_attrs.xml`

Please help. let me know if I need to post all attributes that are showing errors

Comment: Down to 26 errors. Nio more errors in actionbarsherlock. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If the project is using different versions of a same dependency somehow, the problem happens. Try using the same compatible versions for dependencies.